# Identify color of a detected circle in opencv

Tags: colors, opencv, geometry

How would you go about identifying the colors of each detected circle using cvHoughcircles in opencv?
I have added code that shows what i am currently trying but i am getting an error : Unhandled exception at 0x758d9617 in imageTest1.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x0019eed4

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    //load image from directory
    IplImage* img = cvLoadImage("C:\\Users\\Nathan\\Desktop\\SnookerPic.png");


    IplImage* gray = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(img), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
    CvMemStorage* storage = cvCreateMemStorage(0);

    //covert to grayscale
    cvCvtColor(img, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);

    // This is done so as to prevent a lot of false circles from being detected
    cvSmooth(gray, gray, CV_GAUSSIAN, 7, 7);

    IplImage* canny = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(img),IPL_DEPTH_8U,1);
    IplImage* rgbcanny = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(img),IPL_DEPTH_8U,3);
    cvCanny(gray, canny, 50, 100, 3);

    //detect circles
    CvSeq* circles = cvHoughCircles(gray, storage, CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 35.0, 75, 60,0,0);
    cvCvtColor(canny, rgbcanny, CV_GRAY2BGR);

    //draw all detected circles
    for (int i = 0; i < circles->total; i++)
    {
         // round the floats to an int
         float* p = (float*)cvGetSeqElem(circles, i);
         cv::Point center(cvRound(p[0]), cvRound(p[1]));
         int radius = cvRound(p[2]);
cvScalar c;
         c = cvGet2D(img, center.x, center.y);//colour of circle

         // draw the circle center
         cvCircle(img, center, 3, CV_RGB(0,255,0), -1, 8, 0 );

         // draw the circle outline
         cvCircle(img, center, radius+1, CV_RGB(0,0,255), 2, 8, 0 );

         //display coordinates
         printf("x: %d y: %d r: %d\n",center.x,center.y, radius);
    }

    //create window
    cvNamedWindow("circles", 1);
    cvNamedWindow("SnookerImage", 1);
    //show image in window
    cvShowImage("circles", rgbcanny);
    cvShowImage("SnookerImage", img);

    cvSaveImage("out.png", rgbcanny);
    cvWaitKey(0);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can find an identical question here :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7748350/color-detection-on-houghcircles-using-opencv/7750110#7750110

Comment: thanks. i added i the cvScalar code and i am getting an error with the memory location now??

Comment: Can you post your code and error? Maybe we can help more like that.

Comment: i have posted my code and error. I hope you can help

Comment: Well the only error that I see is cvScalar c, which should be CvScalar c. But that should give a compile error. You should debug it and see where it crashes. If you upload the picture on some server and pass the link maybe I'll be able to have a look later.

Comment: thanks. here are the links if ya get a chance. http://nking89.files.wordpress.com/2011/09/screenhunter_03-oct-19-00-03.jpg              http://nking89.files.wordpress.com/2011/09/screenhunter_02-oct-19-00-00.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the coordinates of the current circle that you are trying to get the color for are out of range. You should check for each point if it is in the range of the image (something like center.x > 0 && center.x < image.width && center.y > 0 && center.y < image.height) before trying to get the color for it.

Comment: thanks. I changed the coordinates with integers and it ran so that must be it. I dont know why the centers would be out of range as the image i get after i draw detected circles shows the circle centers inside the image